# Iterating over a column in Pandas DataFrame with groupby conditions

Tags: pandas, iteration

I have a dataset in a pandas DataFrame. Data are sorted by ["Customer_Id","Campaign"].
My goal though is to add another step to the groupby function. For each campaign there is batches, new batches is represented by the New_rank == 1.

[image: How my data looks like now.]

I would like to add a column = "Occurence" that gives me an numbered "batch" for per Customer_Id & campaign.

Desired output like this in this case:

[image]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide your current data, and your desired output, as text (not images)

Comment: Add this to your question `df = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerId':[1]*5+[2]*6,'Campaign':[1]*3+[2,2]+[1]*3+[2]+[3,3],'New_rank':[1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cumsum`:

```
df['Occurence'] = df.groupby(['CustomerId','Campaign'])['New_rank'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    CustomerId  Campaign  New_rank  Occurence
0            1         1         1          1
1            1         1         0          1
2            1         1         1          2
3            1         2         1          1
4            1         2         1          2
5            2         1         1          1
6            2         1         0          1
7            2         1         0          1
8            2         2         1          1
9            2         3         1          1
10           2         3         0          1
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it seems to work fine! Bugged me for a while now... :)